# How many numbers of device can be registered by Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

Is there any *max* numbers of device registering by Azure IoT Hub?
I find [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling) but there are informations only for the total number of messages

Same question for the service **Device Provisioning**.

Comment: Azure Service limits can be found in the  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#service-specific-limits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This document details the limitations of Azure IoTHub: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/iot-hub-limits.md

And according to it now:

> Currently, the maximum number of devices you can connect to a single
>   IoT hub is 1,000,000. If you want to increase this limit, contact
>   Microsoft Support.

So it is by default a million devices for a single IoT Hub.

Comment: Do you know if this number is also related to the service of Device Provisioning? Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I think once a device is added to a specific IoT Hub it should count towards the limit of that hub. If you mean the period of time before the device is added to a specific IoT Hub then from the description and the structure of Device Provisioning it doesn't seem to me the device would be included in this limitation. It doesn't seem there is much documentation about Provisioning service limitations. This document for example provides an update about increasing its limits sometime back but doesn't provide numbers. You can always contact Microsoft to ask for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the numbers for Device Provisioning Service:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/iot-dps-limits.md